# Getting the user to name the variables

Tags: java

For my program i want to have it so that the user can name the variables a bit like in a game you would name your charecter/world. I looked it up and couldn't find anywhere that said if this is possible and if so how it is done.

Comment: Why would you want the user to name the variable? They won't see the variable name anywhere.

Comment: @jhobbie so i could get the user to call the variable later on. So say they named something "stuff" then later on they could input stuff and it would give them the value of it.

Comment: @NatzoHD and how would you do that when the user-input is read as a string?

Comment: You need to read input as a *String* from the user and set its value to the *name* field.

Comment: Create a unique user identifier for the users, then store all information they enter in classes, and have a map or some other data structure (for scaling, a DB) hold the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many others have said, you can't dynamically name variables.

You can however make a Map

It would allow you to create any name for a variable such as "MyTestVar" at runtime and use it as a key in that map to whatever you put:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

String varName = getVariableNameFromUser();
String value = getValueFromUser();

myMap.put(varName, value);


// ... later


String whatVariableDoYouWantTheValueOf = getVarNameFromUser();
String storedValue =  myMap.get(whatVariableDoYouWantTheValueOf);
System.out.println("The value for that is: " + storedValue);
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what i was looking for and will hopefully help.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is create a linked list or an arraylist of some type of object that you create. Your object can then have two properties (or more) where one is the name, and the other is the value. You can then search for an object in your list based on the name, and return the value that you want. This will basically accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a user to name a variable.  All you can do is allow the user to set the variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean is something like giving *Tags* or *Labels* to Objects. "Variable Names" is a missleading wording for that.

After the User typed in the `name` string for an `obj` Object, you could for example use a `HashMap<String, Object>` to store the user input:

```
Map<String, Object> tagToObjectStore = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String userInput = "any Tag name";
Object somethingToLabel = ... // TODO

tagToObjectStore.put(userInput, somethingToLabel); // store the user input

// later in code...

Object theStoredObject = tagToObjectStore.get(userInput); // get the stored object
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: im new to java and was mainly wondering if you could actually get them to name variables but i have seen the comments like these which will help me with my textbased RPG i plan on making